# How do I pass a pre defined callback filter in php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, callback

So I am trying to work with laravel collection filters and I have to filter the collections with a certain callback which looks like so:

```
        $cases->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->invention_id != '' || $item->invention_id != null;
        });
        $total->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->invention_id != '' || $item->invention_id != null;
        });
        $participated->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->invention_id != '' || $item->invention_id != null;
        });
```

So how do I abstract this function and then pass that in all 3? Maybe my PHP basics are weak here but I am not sure.

```
        function filterInventionCases($item)
        {
            return $item->invention_id != '' || $item->invention_id != null;
        }
```

I can do this but then what? How do I pass this in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your callback in the `filter` callback function. Via [OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

```
$cases->filter(function ($item) {
    $this->filterInventionCases($item);
});
$total->filter(function ($item) {
    $this->filterInventionCases($item);
});
$participated->filter(function ($item) {
    $this->filterInventionCases($item);
});
```

or

```
$cases->filter(function ($item) {
    call_user_func('filterInventionCases', $item);
});
$total->filter(function ($item) {
    call_user_func('filterInventionCases', $item);
});
$participated->filter(function ($item) {
    call_user_func('filterInventionCases', $item);
});
```

Laravel `filter` need callable type of callback. Or you can try use PHP `array_filter` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which support string name of the function

```
array_filter($participated->toArray(), "filterInventionCases");
```